# How to display on Kotlin this emoji "smile:\\ud83d\\udd25:" which I got from the server

Tags: android, string, kotlin, server, emoji

I tried a lot of different ways to do it, even tried to remove symbols and replace something, but it did not work for me.
The problem is: I have emoji as smile:\ud83d\udd25: with 2 \ from server, but I need emoji like \ud83d\udd25 - with 1 .

Could you please tell me how can I replace \ on ? I can't use string.replace.
My last try:

```
`val smilesStart = text.substringAfter("smile:").substring(0..11)
            println("smilesStart $smilesStart")

            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(smilesStart).deleteAt(0).deleteAt(5).toString()
            println("stringBuilder $stringBuilder")


            val replaced = text.replace("smile:", "").replace("\\ud83d\\udd25", smilesStart)
            return EmojiCompat.get().process(smilesStart)`
```

BUT it did not get \ as teo different symbols...

Please help me!

tried dealing with strings functions

Comment: somehow here I have normal smile code: \ud83d\udd25 but from server got this  \\ud83d\\udd25